# MySQL error when trying to import tablespace

Tags: mysql, percona, percona-server

I'm following the steps described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-table-import.html), but the import of one of the tables is failing with the error below. It's a large table, with a ~22GB `.idb` file.

`[ERROR] [MY-012762] [InnoDB] Page offset doesn't match file offset: page offset: 262144, file offset: 262144`

For what is worth, I'm using Percona 8 and not the vanila MySQL.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You have a different error but afaik there's an existing bug with partial backups in PS 8.0 and PXB 8.0 - https://jira.percona.com/browse/PXB-2132. what version of xtrabackup are you using?

Comment: actually this is related to this bug filed just today - https://jira.percona.com/browse/PS-7095